# How long does it take Google to update all links from R 301?

Tags: seo

I just changed the location of my blog, and have done the appropriate redirects. Does anyone have knowledge or experience for the delay in updating all the links across Google?

Reason I ask, I wish to change the A record. So this will eliminate the .htaccess file, and thus null and void the redirect.

How long must I wait prior to the undertaking?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As codeka said, it can take many weeks for every page to be updated. And don't forget if you go ahead and remove the redirects by changing the A record, any links still pointing to the old location will now be invalid.

If you haven't done so already, log into Google Webmaster Tools, add your new domain as a site, then go to "Change of address" to let Google know you've moved the site.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the site. Some sites (e.g. ones that get updated frequently) get reindexed pretty quickly (every day, even). Others may take a month or two. For the best chance of it having picked it up, I would give it around 3 months.

Alternatively, you can just do a search for your site every few days and check which version Google is returning.

Answer (score 0):

The 301 redirect is a "permanent" redirect, so you should be ready to keep it for quite some time :-).

Google mentions other things to look at in the Help Center article at http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=83105 -- in particular I'd recommend working to make sure that old links to your site are updated accordingly (take the time to try to contact people linking to your site, you can find the links in Webmaster Tools).